# Having issues exiting app on double press

Tags: java, android

So I've implemented a double press to exit on my mainactivity which exits fine if I go to settings activity or to game activity. However, if I go mainactivity --> gameactivity --> gameoveractivity and then press back it starts the mainactivity fine but then double pressing just returns to gameoveractivity and I'm not sure why as I call finish when starting mainactivity from gameoveractivity.

mainscreenactivity:

```
// button listeners
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent gameActivityIntent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                startActivity(gameActivityIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.righttocenter, R.anim.centertoleft);
                finish();
            }

        });

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent settingsActivityIntent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                MainScreenActivity.this.startActivity(settingsActivityIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.righttocenter, R.anim.centertoleft);
            }

        });
```

gameactivity:

```
// handle hardware back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent mainScreenActivityIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainScreenActivityIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.lefttocenter, R.anim.centertoright);
        finish();
    }
```

logic code to handle going to gameoveractivity:

```
if (weight.getBounds().intersect(player.getBounds())) {
                timer.cancel();
                gameTimer.cancel();
                player.setTouched(false);
                save(score, time);
                Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(this.getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
                this.getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
                ((Activity) this.getContext()).finish();
            }
```

gameoveractivity:

```
// handle hardware back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent mainScreenActivityIntent = new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        mainScreenActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        GameOverActivity.this.startActivity(mainScreenActivityIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.lefttocenter, R.anim.centertoright);
        finish();
    }
```

**Edit:** Managed to fix this by adding this: `gameOverIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
in the game logic code after creating the gameoveractivityintent.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by adding this:

```
gameOverIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

in the game logic code after creating the gameoveractivityintent.